# php rss feed show images

Tags: php, image, rss, feed

I am trying to show the images in the following rss feed and would appreciate help from somebody please. I have tried getAttribute but am not sure how to format it or where in the code to put it, so I have taken it out to avoid confusion. The following code is working, but I need to add the code to display the images.

```
<?php

$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://xml.thinkspain.com/think-spain-feeds/spanish-news.xml');

$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array ( 
 'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
 'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
 'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
 'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
 );
array_push($feed, $item);
} 

$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
$title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
$link = $feed[$x]['link'];
$description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
$date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}  

?>
```

Comment: Read this http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_image.asp

Comment: thanks Paul, but the RSS feed is not written using the image tag, it uses 'enclosure'. I didn't write it myself, so I can't change it. I need to access the url attribute inside the 'enclosure' tag please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get attribute by using `getAttribute` :

```
$node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')
```

Comment: wonderful, that works! First time I posted a question on stackoverflow, thanks so much for the help, I had spent hours at it, but you got me the answer really quickly, I appreciate.