# Grab images with php from an rss feed

Tags: php, rss

PHP

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://www.autoexpress.co.uk/feeds/all');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
  $item = array (
    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('whattagdoiaddhere')->item(0)->nodeValue,
  );
  array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 3;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
  $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
  $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
  $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
  $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
  echo '<div class="news-row-index">';
  echo '<div class="img"><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="'.$title.'"><img src="'.$image.'" height="79" width="89"></a></div>';
  echo '<div class="details-index"><p><h5><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></h5><br />';
  echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
  echo '<p>'.$description.'</p></div>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

1. I am trying to get the images from [this rss](http://www.autoexpress.co.uk/feeds/all) but don't know exactly how to get the image and add it into the `<div class="img"`.
2. Also i have a problem because the image is being received but it's located in the `$description` variable.
3. Tried searching and found [php rss feed show images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939039/php-rss-feed-show-images) but when i add the code from that answer I get nothing in the rss module.
   Please help me I really appreciate it.

Comment: do you want to grab the images in the description node?

Comment: @Nouphal.M I want to grab them in the `<div class="img">`. If you are referring from where to grab them. Yes, i want the first image from the description tag of the rss. Like for example on the first rss news feed, want to get the image with the VW Amarok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of DomDocument loadHTML to parse the description field and grab the image tags.

```
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
  $htmlStr = $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $html = new DOMDocument();        
  $html->loadHTML($htmlStr);
   //get the first image tag from the description HTML
   $img = $html->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
   $item = array (
    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'image' => $img,
  );
  array_push($feed, $item);
}
  print_r($feed);
```

Also to check if the DOMNodeList is empty, try

```
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
      $htmlStr = $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $html = new DOMDocument();        
      $html->loadHTML($htmlStr);
       //get the first image tag from the description HTML
        $imgTag = $html->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $img = ($imgTag->length==0)?'noimg.png':$imgTag->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
       $item = array (
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'image' => $img,
      );
      array_push($feed, $item);
    }
```

Comment: integrate it in my rss feed like [this](http://pastebin.com/EyQuqvXP) and still not getting nothing on the image.

Comment: in your html part change from `$image` to `$feed[$x]['image']`

Comment: Try this `echo '<div class="img"><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="'.$title.'"><img src="'.$feed[$x]['image'].'" height="79" width="89"></a></div>';`

Comment: It's much appreciated for the image.